# react,js images are not displaying both on local host and github pages

Tags: reactjs, image

my image are in the public directory I still don't know why isn't displaying on both my local host and GitHub pages

I have tried checking the path and still getting the same issue, I even tried moving the images into my main folder directory but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use images inside components or pages, you should move them into **src** folder and for best practice, you should store them in **assets** folder inside src.
but if you just only want to use them inside public folder, for instance in index.html file, you should write href(src) like **%PUBLIC_URL%/your_img.png**

Answer (score 0):

You have import the images into your component like this:

```
import image from "./public/image.svg"
```